# Why use a promise when implementing ControlValueAccessor's writeValue method?

Tags: angular, es6-promise, angular-material2

I am in reference to **angular material 2's autocomplete** source code which can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts).

The `MdAutocompleteTrigger` implements `ControlValueAccessor`. Here is the implementation for the `writeValue` method:

```
/**
   * Sets the autocomplete's value. Part of the ControlValueAccessor interface
   * required to integrate with Angular's core forms API.
   *
   * @param value New value to be written to the model.
   */
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this._setTriggerValue(value));
  }
```

Can someone please explain the need for using a Promise here?

Comment: It's used to prevent `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Comment: Thanks a lot Yurzui. Now can someone please explain why and how resorting to promise helps prevent `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` ?

Comment: I looked at `_setTriggerValue` code and now i doubt :)

Comment: `Promise.resolve` shedules new microtask and in some cases when we are updating something that has already checked it helps to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I investigated a bit. It's related with https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L328-L338. Without microtask autocomplete will emit valueChange event and for example these two tests will fall https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete.spec.ts#L1026-L1076

Comment: Thanks for the update!